# Automatically reboot if boot into maintenance mode

Tags: 18.04

For some reason my Ubuntu 18.04 server restarted last night (power loss I suspect) and it rebooted into maintenance mode. After using ILO2 to get remote access and reboot, the system started fine again.

Is there anyway to automatically restart the system if it boots into maintenance mode?